# FreePascal: convert SmallInt to ShortString?

Tags: casting, freepascal

I'm trying to debug some code. The function that prints debug messages to the screen expects a shortstring, but I want to pass a smallint to it somehow. This is the code I have:

```
dialogmsg('MapTile ' + ShortString( MyInteger ));
```

I get this message however when compiling the program:

```
Error: Illegal type conversion: "SmallInt" to "ShortString"
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`IntToStr`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/inttostr.html) in `sysstrh.inc`.

```
dialogMsg('MapTile ' + IntToStr(MyInteger));
```

Comment: I'm new to Pascal. How do I include that file, and where can I find it?

Comment: @posfan12 add sysutils to your uses clause